# Installing ZFDebug toolbar on ZF 1.10+

Tags: debugging, zend-framework, toolbar

I think it'll be good to have a ZFDebug tutorial in SO.

I was wondering if you could use `ZFDebug toolbar` with `ZF 1.10+` (I'm actually using `1.11.2`). I have the following code in my bootstrap but nothing seems to happen:

```
protected function _initZFDebug()
{
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace('ZFDebug');

    if ('development' == APPLICATION_ENV) {
     $options = array(
       'jquery_path' => 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js',
       'plugins' => array('Variables',
       'Html',
       'Database' => array(),
       'File' => array('basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/application'),
       'Memory',
       'Time',
       'Registry',
       //'Cache' => array('backend' => $cache->getBackend()),
       'Exception')
     );
     $debug = new ZFDebug_Controller_Plugin_Debug($options);

     $this->bootstrap('frontController');
     $frontController = $this->getResource('frontController');
     $frontController->registerPlugin($debug);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you get it to work? how did you do it ?

Comment: @max4ever - see the (only) answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure your `APPLICATION_ENV` is set to `'development'`
2. Make sure to have a **valid** layout (with `<head>` and `<body>`)
3. the basePath option should be `APPLICATION_PATH . '/../'`